# Record not visible for Community users through Apex class

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, sharing-rule

We have an Apex class which provides data for our mobile app(sdk not sf1) through an API. This app users are of community users.

The Apex class used here is declared as Without Sharing but when users search for the records, they cannot able to see few records. We found that it is due to Sharing settings which Apex class is not taking under consideration.

We have modified our OWD settings to public read for the object and even then, we are facing the same issue.

I have read that community users have some issues with Sharing settings and is this issue related to that?
Please suggest.

Comment: Did you change the sharing for External access?

Comment: Yes I did. Even then, we are seeing only limited records
Where as in anonymous window, we can able to see all records. Is there anything that we can configure to get this done? Please suggest

Comment: anonymous Apex runs with full permission of the user. Verify that how you have shared the records to community members (by Sharing Set or Sharing Group)

Comment: In External Sharing Access, we have put the access as Read only for the object records that we are querying. Even then, we are seeing the limited records

Comment: Which object records you are querying?

Comment: We are querying for Sponsor Records
But these sponsors records have "Controlled by Parent Access". Account is the Parent of these Sponsor Records.
As Account was set to Public Read Mode, we thought we could achieve it but tough luck, we can only see limited records